# No coverage report with JSCover

Tags: phantomjs, qunit, jscoverage

I am following this guide to generate javascript coverage report on Ubuntu 13.04:

http://tysonlloydcadenhead.com/blog/javascript-test-coverage-with-jscoverage#.UhnokxIW2Y4

I have installed PhantomJS 1.9.1. I have downloaded JSCover-1.0.3 and extracted it into the root of the workspace. The structure looks like this:

```
workspace
 -> src/core/core.js
 -> src/core/parser.js
 -> test/coreTest/coreTest.js
 -> test/coreTest/parserTest.js
 -> JSCover-1.0.3/target/dist/JSCover-all.jar
 -> JSCover-1.0.3/src/test/javascript/lib/PhantomJS/run-jscover-qunit.js
 -> all_tests.html
```

First I start the server in the root of the workspace:

```
workspace$ java -jar JSCover-1.0.3/target/dist/JSCover-all.jar -ws --document-root=. --report-dir=coverage
```

Next I run the all_tests.html

```
workspace$ phantomjs JSCover-1.0.3/src/test/javascript/lib/PhantomJS/run-jscover-qunit.js all_tests.htm

'waitFor()' finished in 2457ms.
Tests completed in 2300 milliseconds.
13 assertions of 13 passed, 0 failed.
```

But when I look in the workspace/coverage dir it only contains (both are empty):

```
jscover.log 
jscover.log.lck
```

Why is the coverage report not created?

Answer (score 1):

Try `phantomjs JSCover-1.0.3/src/test/javascript/lib/PhantomJS/run-jscover-qunit.js http://localhost:8080/all_tests.htm`